# scanning a system for shared folders in lan

Tags: apache-flex, networking

I am developing an application in flex 3 using action script 3.........
I have some range of ip address in LAN(wired or wireless both).....i want to check which all the systems available...and also want to see their shared folders.....can anyone give some code or reference in action script....

Thanks to everyone...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think it's possible at all with Flex due to sandbox violation of the Flash Player and/or not supporting it.

I don't know if Air supports network access in this way. Check [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/) out for more information on Adobe Air.

Answer (score 0):

MysticEarth is right, Flex cannot access the operating system directly because of security issues that might arise.

However, you can solve it in two ways:

1. [Adobe AIR 2.0 Command-Line Integration](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/preview-command-line-integration-in-adobe-air-2):
2. Server-side script

Adobe AIR 2.0 can now run native processes!  So you could have it access your operating system, check the systems available, shared folders, etc.  Here's an example on [how to execute native processes with AIR 2.0](http://www.flexpasta.com/index.php/2009/12/01/command-line-execution-in-air-20/)

The current standard is to just use Flex and HTTP to a server side script.  To do something like what you're describing, I would create a ruby/php/python script or whatever, send a restful GET HTTP request to that script (say `GET /shared_folders`), and have that search the OS for what it needs, and return it as XML.  Then you can use Flex.  If you don't want to do that, AIR 2.0 is the only option.